# strings are over-writing variables when using echo

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

I've currently got an IP address in a variable and I'm trying to echo that variable with some string at the end:

```
echo $INTERFACE_IP
echo ":0.0"
echo "${INTERFACE_IP}:0.0"
```

And what I'm getting is:

```
192.168.240.238
:0.0
:0.0168.240.238
```

Expected output for the third line:

```
192.168.240.238:0.0
```

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
PS="/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe"

INTERFACE_INDEX=`${PS} Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "Cisco*" | awk '{print $8}'`
INTERFACE_IP=`${PS} Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPV4 -InterfaceIndex ${INTERFACE_INDEX} | grep IPAddress | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed 's/ //g'`

echo $INTERFACE_IP                                                                                                                
echo ":0.0"

echo "$INTERFACE_IP:0.0"

export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
```

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is the contents of INTERFACE_IP not being what you expect.... trailing CR?

Comment: I'm pretty sure PowerShell is producing output in DOS/Windows text format, which includes a carriage return character (aka CR, `\r`, or `^M`) at the end of each line.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ahh, you know I was thinking something along those lines and dos2unix'd the file itself because I use WSL2 and sometimes create files in my Windows IDE. Please submit this as a solution and I'll check back later if it works.

Comment: @GordonDavisson you were right, this solved the problem:
`sed -e 's/ //g' -e 's/\\r//g'`

Comment: @doublespaces I don't have a WSL2 system handy to check the syntax; why don't you write up the solution you found as a self-answer?